# How many ways you can make change for an amount N using A and B monets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I encountered a quite interesting problem. The question is: How many ways you can make change for an amount N using monets of value A and B, knowing that GCD(A,B)=1.
Any idea how to solve this? It reminds me combinatorial class and generating functions. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: The answer depends on N. If you have coins of 2 and 5 you can not make N = 3. The Frobenius number determines the highest N that A and B can not solve for. (2-1)(5-1)-1 = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3402584

I am assuming that monets are some kind of currency. The generating function for the number of ways is

$$G(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1-x^A\right) \left(1-x^B\right)}$$

you would check the coefficient of $x^N$

The Frobenius number $(A-1)(B-1)-1$ tells us the highest N that can not be represented by any combination of A and B.

Comment: i know how to use generating function when given N and A,B. The problem is when its unknown. Also i dont rly know what is the purpose of GCD here.

Comment: how do your reach this formula above? I know that 1+x+x^2+x^3+...=(1/1-x). It seems G(x)=GA(x)*GB(x) and that GA(x)=1+x^A+(x^A)^2+(x^A)^3....

Comment: The G(x) I wrote is to partition N into an unlimited number of A's and B's. Your GA(x) is not correct because the A's should not get raised to a power.

Comment: @user3402584, both are the same. Note that $(x^A)^k = x^{k A}$

Comment: Oh Lord yes, got confused sorry.